# Currency Rate not importing correctly from Webservicex

Tags: magento-1.9, currency

For the past few days it seems Magento's default currency rate updater has not been working. [image: screenshot of System > Manage Currency > Rates]

As you can see, after I click import, most of the currency rates show 1:1 which is obviously not right. We are on Magento CE 1.9.2.1.

Comment: are you able to see if cron is running?

Comment: > are you able to see if cron is running? – rob3000 26 mins ago. I have a same issue. I'm on Magento CE 1.7. I run cron for auto import rates of currency.
Can you help me about this issue?

Answer (score 25):

The issue, as others have pointed out, is that the WebserviceX is now returning a -1 for all currency conversions. Until this is fixed I suggest you use another exchange API.

I suggest Fixer.io.

I have coded a module which will allow you to easily switch between the two.

https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_Fixerio

Comment: million thanks guys! magento should use this as default exchange service...

Comment: Tested in 1.9.3.4 it shows 'Cannot retrieve rate from https://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD&symbols=AED'

Comment: Add a license key in CMS: fixer.io under system > currency settings > fixer.io

Answer (score 4):

The webservicex.net application that does the conversion for Magento seems to be not working.

Scroll down to the Test section on this page - no matter what currencies you enter it's returning -1 (for the GET responses at least)

http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?op=ConversionRate

Its failed in the past and come back - hopefully the same this time but who knows. I've sent an email to support@webservicex.net but it bounced back

Comment: I installed this extension to resolve:  http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/payserv-googlefinance.html   Am sure philwinkle's module works also

Comment: Thanks for providing the testing URL. That's what I was looking for. I can indeed confirm the -1 response right now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Webservicex -  not working
2. Google Finance - not working
3. Plugin https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_Fixerio  for fixer.io works perfect when applayed API_key  and changed address to new one but free version only with base currency EUR.
4. Google Finance stop working but I change in this plugin to use xe.com and its working with different base currencies.
   https://github.com/ausger/GoogleCurrency   If changes not accepted they should be in pull request.