# How to integrate fixer.io currency converter

Tags: api, currency, install-script

We want to enable currency switcher to our store. We checked this tutorial to add currency options http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/ But "WebservicesX" is not fetching any rates.
[image: Not fetching current rates]

As a different thread mentioned, a solution was to use Fixer.io API. [Currency Rate not importing correctly from Webservicex](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91292/currency-rate-not-importing-correctly-from-webservicex)

Does anyone have idea on how to install this API to Magento backend, in order to enable it? )I´ve downloaded all the Git folders there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes simply install the module Phil Winkle developed.

It is available here: https://github.com/philwinkle/Philwinkle_Fixerio

The process to configure it is exactly the same as WebserviceX

Comment: any idea on how to proceed with the module installation process? (Upload any files through the FTP for example, or call through magento interface for some file). I will appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. 
I just added the files under the "app" folder, to their subroot folders on the same paths, through the FTP client.

Seems to be working fine now.